# RedirectView and url reverse with optional args

Tags: django

Short: i'm trying to do a simple redirect view to a third party app provided named url, with optional parameters

Third party view url ( from provider.oauth2 package ) is registered like this

```
url('^authorize/?$',login_required(Capture.as_view()), name='capture'),
```

I've imported this urlconf in namespace='oauth2'
In my view this works fine:

```
class RedirectToCapture(RedirectView):
    pattern_name = 'oauth2:capture'

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RedirectToCapture,self).get_redirect_url(*args,**kwargs)
```

This will fail to reverse() url because there are no optional parameters defined in the urlpattern above

```
class RedirectToCapture(RedirectView):
    pattern_name = 'oauth2:capture'

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['response_type'] = 'code'
        return super(RedirectToCapture,self).get_redirect_url(*args,**kwargs)
```

This hack works

```
class RedirectToCapture(RedirectView):
    pattern_name = 'oauth2:capture'
    query_string = True

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request.META['QUERY_STRING'] = urlencode({'response_type' :'code')
        return super(RedirectToCapture,self).get_redirect_url(*args,**kwargs)
```

This is super ugly. Another way, doing reverse() myself and omitting pattern_name

```
class RedirectToCapture(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url = reverse('oauth2:capture') + '?' + urlencode({'response_type' :'code' })
        return super(RedirectToCapture,self).get_redirect_url(*args,**kwargs)
```

Is this the cleanest way ? 
Touching either args or kwargs in any way causes reverse() to stop matching

PS: And yes i want to use a class based view here derived from RedirectView for multiple unrelated reasons. I know i can simply do http.HttpResponseRedirect(url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very nearly there. In your final version you can just to return the url instead of calling super.

```
class RedirectToCapture(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        get_args = urlencode({'response_type' :'code' })
        return reverse('oauth2:capture') + '?' + get_args
```

Comment: Right, looking at RedirectView code it really doesnt do much else there so yep that call is pointless. 
It does use 
url = "%s?%s" % (url, args) 
which seems better preferred style so i guess i'll do that too